# There is a blank border around the Sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

There is a background sprite in my code.
Then I added a child sprite on it.
But when the child sprite run a CCTwirl action(including other CCGridAction),there is a black border around the sprite.
I want to know how to get rid of the blank border?
the child sprite is not full screen.
Thx!!!

Comment: I added a background ccsprite to current scene. then I added an child ccsprite in the scene over the background ccsprite. it works good now. but when the child ccsprite run an action like the following code. the black border appear. childSprite->runAction(CCLiquid::create(1, 1.5f, ccg(12, 12), 0.6));

Answer (score 0):

CCTwirl and CCLiquid are "3D" effects, inheriting from CCGrid3DAction. If you want to use any such "3D" effect like actions or transitions in your game, you may have to enable 3D projection (cocos2d 2.x defaults to 2D projection).

You can change the projection via the CCDirector property `projection`.

Comment: thank you very much. but when i set the projection to kCCDirectorProjection3D, the blank border still be there.